When exactly does the miner get their reward?
When exactly does the miner get their reward via the coinbase tx?
Say I am a miner and I have mined a block. I broadcast it to peers A, B, and C and they then broadcast it to their peers and so on. When do I get my reward? When A's chain accepts my block as the most recent one?
(split from Can multiple candidate blocks be mined concurrently by the miner, even if at the end only one block gets added to the chain every 10 mins?)

Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/111335/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/61833/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/66713/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/92280/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/49046/5406

The mined block contains a "coinbase" transaction the miner created to pay himself
Outputs of the coinbase cannot be spent until at least a further 100 blocks have been mined on top of this block.
